# Should I flag iOS-questions on app crashes which don't contain a backtrace?

Tags: discussion

In the iOS-tag there are often questions of the form "i do this - and it crashes", without a backtrace and without a proper error message.

Recently, I added a paragraph to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/info) that says:

> Please follow the article [My App crashed. Now
>   what?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)
>   by Ray Wenderlich, before posting any questions relating to app
>   crashes. It explains how to properly debug an iOS-App. It's pointless
>   to ask questions relating to crashes when you don't have a *proper*
>   backtrace and exception message.

and it was approved. What should I do with low-quality questions about such crashes? Downvote? Flag? If I should flag it, which flag? it's certainly not a duplicate, because there are 100000000 reasons for a crash, only the cure is always the same on iOS: 1) create an exception breakpoint 2) run the program 3) let it crash 4) read the error message 5) think. Point 1) is the most important point, and the one that is usually missing.

I'm not saying that all questions about crashes are bad. If you have a proper backtrace and you can point to the exact place where the crash happened, and if you have a crash message different from "it crashed in main.m, line 12", then it's okay. but these questions usually don't happen, because if you know the line where the exception is thrown, and if you can comprehend the wording of the exception message, it is usually trivial to fix it. for the rare cases where it isn't a trivial fix, it's okay to ask a question on SO...

Comment: Close as "lacking information", and leave a helpful comment if you feel like it.

Comment: There is a closing code for "lacks sufficient information to diagnose".  I generally ask for the info once or twice, then vote that closing code if it's not forthcoming.

Comment: I would say do the same as what some are doing when that happens on Android. They link them to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/3204827) question and flag it as a duplicate. There might be a version of that for iOS or flag it to close and link it to Ray's blog post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to iOS apps.  Anytime the question does not contain enough information to answer without listing 100000000 different possibilities then flag/vote to close the question with any of the following:

1. Off-Topic/Lacks Sufficient Information
2. Unclear what you are asking
3. Too Broad

In most cases, "Lacks Sufficient Information" would be the most applicable since that is literally why the question can't be answered.

"Unclear" would also be very appropriate in many of these cases and may be more applicable for the good ole "My app crashes and here is my entire code" without any additional information since a code dump and no real problem statement does not make it a clear question.

"Too Broad" could cover many of these same topics since answers would have to cover many/all possibilities when this info is not provided, but personally, I think this should be only used when the other 2 reasons can't be applied.

Comment: I'll add to this: don't wait for the OP to respond to comments requesting more info! Vote/flag ***immediately***, so the question gets closed before half a dozen "helpful" folk plug in their crystal balls and post either uselessly general advice or pointlessly specific guesses.